# Find if alarm is already set? If possible find time left before the next alarm trigger

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-wake-lock

I have set an alarm using AlarmManager and PendingIntent. The app has text counter which is a typical timer clock that counts backwards until it reaches 0. I would like to know whether a alarm is already set so that I can update my text counter and start/stop button states accordingly if my activity is killed and restored.

Question/Problem:

1. isAlarmActive flag value is always TRUE.
2. Returns true even if app is uninstalled and re-installed.

Used solution from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556670/how-to-check-if-alarmmamager-already-has-an-alarm-set#answer-9575569) but doesnt seem to work. Any help will be great.

---

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ....
     boolean isAlarmActive = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, 
            new Intent(INTENT_ALARM_ACTION), 
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

     if(isAlarmActive)
       changeButtonStatus(ButtonStatus.STOP);
     else
       changeButtonStatus(ButtonStatus.STARt);

}

private OnClickListener mBtnListener = new OnClickListener() 
    {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(mButtonStatus == ButtonStatus.START){
           setAlarmOnAlarmManager();
           changeButtonStatus(ButtonStatus.STOP);
        }else{
           cancelAlarmOnAlarmManager();
           changeButtonStatus(ButtonStatus.START);
        }
    }        

public void setAlarmOnAlarmManager()
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        long triggerTime = cal.getTimeInMillis() + mAlarmInterval;
        mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, mPendingIntent);
    }

public void cancelAlarmOnAlarmManager()
   {
        MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        mAlarmManager.cancel(mPendingIntent);
        unregisterReceiver(mAlarmReceiver);
   }
```

Comment: how and where is the variable `mPendingIntent` set?

Comment: Have a look: https://justanapplication.wordpress.com/tag/pendingintent-getbroadcast/. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273297/pendingintent-getbroadcast-never-returns-null. Are you sure you are not creating a matching pending intent some place else ?